# HashMap not returning image to marker by onMarkerClick

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a marker created by camera intent and then returned to the map as a thumbnail.  Now what i want to do is to tap on the marker to display the full image for each marker that is added. Previously i can display the image in full screen, but it only displays the last image taken for all the markers and not the individual images for each marker.

Here is my code:

```
Bitmap bitmap;
private String TAG;
File destinationFile;
public static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_THUMBNAIL_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1888;
private Map<File, String> markerImagePathMap;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_googlemaps);
        markerImagePathMap = new HashMap<File, String>();


  try {
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }


private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();

    if (googleMap!=null){
      }

 CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
         new LatLng(xx.xxxx, xx.xxxx)).zoom(9).bearing(0).tilt(80).build();

 googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
 googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
 googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
 googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
 googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
 googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
 googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
 googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
 googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
}


public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng point) {

      googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
              marker.remove();
            }
      });
      Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
      startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_THUMBNAIL_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
  }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{ 
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_THUMBNAIL_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        File imageStorageFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"My Folder");
        if (!imageStorageFolder.exists())
        {
            imageStorageFolder.mkdirs();
            Log.d(TAG , "Folder created at: "+imageStorageFolder.toString());
        }
        if (data != null)
        {
            String filename = "image";
            String fileNameExtension = ".jpg";
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            String imageStorageFolder1 = File.separator+"My Folder"+File.separator;
            destinationFile = new File(sdCard, imageStorageFolder1 + filename + fileNameExtension);
            Log.d(TAG, "the destination for image file is: " + destinationFile );
            if (data.getExtras() != null)
            {
                bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
                try
                {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "ERROR:" + e.toString());
                }
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                            .draggable(true)
                            .snippet("Snippet")
                            .title("Title")
                            .position(position)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .fromBitmap(bitmap));
                            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                            Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                            markerImagePathMap.put(destinationFile, marker.getId());
            }
        }
    }
 }
        public void onMapClick (LatLng point){
    }
 {
 }
    @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick (Marker marker){

        markerImagePathMap.put(destinationFile, marker.getId());         
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            markerImagePathMap.put(destinationFile, marker.getId());
            Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + markerImagePathMap.get(marker.getId()));
            intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
          return false;
  }
 }
```

But the problem is that it isn't displaying any image when tapping on the marker it just displays this image (file not found or broken or something to that effect)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do like this:

```
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + markerImagePathMap.get(marker.getId())
```

you need to do like this:

```
markerImagePathMap.put(marker.getId(), destinationFile);
```

So the code should be like this:

```
private Map<String, File> markerImagePathMap;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    markerImagePathMap = new HashMap<String, File>();
    ...
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    ...
    //destinationFile = new File(sdCard, imageStorageFolder1 + filename + fileNameExtension);  // <--- Delete
    File destinationFile = new File(sdCard, imageStorageFolder1 + filename + fileNameExtension);  // <--- Add
    ...
    Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    Log.d(TAG, marker.getId() + " -> " + destinationFile.getAbsolutePath());   // <--- Add
    markerImagePathMap.put(marker.getId(), destinationFile);
    ...
}

public boolean onMarkerClick (Marker marker){
    ...
    //markerImagePathMap.put(destinationFile, marker.getId());  <-- what is this for?
    File destinationFile = markerImagePathMap.get(marker.getId())
    Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + destinationFile.getAbsolutePath());
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help, but still getting that image? I thinkit is not reading the path correctly.

Comment: You also misunderstand the File class. The File class is not string. So you need to call `file.getAbsolutePath()`. I updated the code.

Comment: I have actually tried that earlier but the app then crashes with `12-11 19:57:44.237: E/AndroidRuntime(5818): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 19:57:44.237: E/AndroidRuntime(5818): Process: com.map.cityguide, PID: 5818
12-11 19:57:44.237: E/AndroidRuntime(5818): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-11 19:57:44.237: E/AndroidRuntime(5818):  at com.map.cityguide.Test.onMarkerClick(Test.java:212)`

Comment: I am starting to think that this might be impossible to map that image to that specific marker :-)

Comment: Its This one : `Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + destinationFile.getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: In that case, I wonder there is really existed the file when you create a marker. I update the code, check it out.

Comment: Hi,  It still seem to crash, this time at Line 213 `intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");`,  any ideas why?  am going to see what i can find and let you know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66772/discussion-between-wf9a5m75-and-allrounder).